# How can I set container folders as non-containers when child items are restricted to a different resource group?

Tags: css, modx, zurb-foundation, modx-revolution

As the title says, "How can I set container folders as non-containers when child items are restricted to a different resource group"?

I'm using the foundation 3 framework and came into some trouble with drop-down & fly-out menus being not populated because the user is not logged in.  I need to somehow toggle the container flag off when a user has no access to the child items so that wayfinder does not insert the &parentClass.

Answer (score 0):

Container status is set by **isfolder**'s value.

Wayfinder doesn't check whether the resource's children are accessible or not.

Try [getResources](http://jasoncoward.com/technology/2013/06/finding-your-way-without-wayfinder.html) to build your menu.